# WCF (.NET 4.0) long delay in AuthenticateRequest state in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis-7

We have a set of WCF (.NET 4.0) services hosted in IIS7. We recently observed strange behaviour on production:

In IIS7 we opened the 'Current requests in the worker process' view for one of them (the most often called) and noticed that many request are 
listed in AuthenticateRequest state (ModuleName = ServiceModel-4.0) with time elapsed reaching up to a few seconds and then they disappear.
We don't really use any authentication in this service.

AuthenticateRequest is a very early stage in the pipeline and we're wondering what could be holding them up there?
We tried increasing the maxConcurrentCalls limit but that didn't seem to have any effect.

- Is this abnormal behaviour?
- I assume our application code has not been executed at this stage, yet, is this correct?
- If this is a contention of some sort what could be the problematic resource? We have mutliple WCF services running on that machine.

Thanks,
Piotr

Comment: What authentication scheme is in play? (Windows/NTLM?) If so, what's the user or account context -- local, or Active Directory? If it's somehow backed by DB, look to the DB for bottlenecking and starvation.

Comment: We have Anonymous Authenticaton enabled. The ASP.NET impersonation and forms authentiction are disabled. 

The application pools are setup to use a local NetworkService account.

There is no Domain Controller in this environment at all.

Comment: Does the machine have AV with realtime or on-access type scanning?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  There's a group of 10 WCF services installed there. Most of them have (basicHttpBinding, some netMsmqBinding (two may have netTcpBinding). It's an EC2 instance, high end specification. There's quite a bit of traffic hitting it. I had a quick look at implementation of that ServiceModule and it seems that it just registers itself post AuthenticationRequest step, so it may not necesserily be related to authentication as such. Still, I'd love to understand what is going on here, do we have some sort of resource contention problem? Thanks, Piotr.

Answer (score 0):

We got an explanation on the MSDN WCF forum 
(http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c6045491-d266-431e-8c02-dbdece5dd1bd/#e573f8e0-2ca5-4514-a635-eadb2cb848a5).

It is the actual application code that is executing here.

Thanks,
Piotr